# Combine different "containers" in cats XorT

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monad-transformers, scala-cats

For example, we have some services with different "containers" `Future` and `Option`:

```
//first service with Future
class FirstService { 
      getData(): XorT[Future, ServiceError, SomeData]
}

//second service with Optin
class SecondService {
      getData(): XorT[Option, ServiceError, SomeData]
}
```

How do we can combine them to use one for comprehension to avoid type mismatch?

```
val result = for {
    data1 <- firstService.getData()
    data2 <- secondService.getData() // type mismatch required XorT[Future, ServiceError, SomeData]
} yield mergeResult(data1, data2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible ways to solve this problem make common `Container` monad for different types (`Future`, `Option`):

```
trait Container[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Container[B]
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Container[B]): Container[B]
}
// Empty container for value
class EmptyContainer[+A](value: A) extends Container[A] {
  override def map[B](f: (A) => B): Container[B] = new EmptyContainer[B](f(value))
  override def flatMap[B](f: (A) => Container[B]): Container[B] = f(value)
}
// Implement container for Option
class OptionContainer[+A](option: Option[A]) extends Container[A] {
  override def map[B](f: (A) => B): Container[B] = new OptionContainer[B](option.map(f))
  override def flatMap[B](f: (A) => Container[B]): Container[B] = option match {
    case Some(value) => f(value)
    case None => new OptionContainer[B](None)
  }
}
// Implement container for Future
class FutureContainer[+A](future: Future[A]) extends Container[A] {
  override def map[B](f: (A) => B): Container[B] = new FutureContainer[B](future.map(f))
  // TODO: can be better!!!
  override def flatMap[B](f: (A) => Container[B]): Container[B] = {
    val promise = Promise[B]()
    future.onComplete {
      case Success(a) => f(a).map(b => promise.success(b))
      case Failure(exception) => promise.failure(exception)
    }
    new FutureContainer[B](promise.future)
  }
}
```

You can add an own implementation for any others types.

```
// Monad for Container
object Container {
  implicit def monad = new Monad[Container] {
    def flatMap[A, B](fa: Container[A])(f: (A) => Container[B]): Container[B] = fa.flatMap(f)
    def pure[A](x: A): Container[A] = new EmptyContainer[A](x)
  }
}
```

Our service now has view:

```
class SomeContainerService {
  def getSomeDate(): XorT[Container, Error, SomeData] =
    XorT.right(Option(SomeData()).toContainer)

  def getRemoteDate(): XorT[Container, Error, SomeData] =
    XorT.right(Future(SomeData()).toContainer)
}
```

Extensions methods for both future and option:

```
def toContainer = OptionContainer(option)
def toContainer = FutureContainer(future)
```

And for-comprehension work fine:

```
val result: XorT[Container, Error, SomeData] = for {
  data1 <- someContainerService.getRemoteDate() // future
  data2 <- someContainerService.getSomeDate()   // option
} yield {
  mergeResult(data1, data2)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`XorT[F, A, B]` is just a convenient wrapper over `F[A Xor B]`, so you question essentially is: how to combine a `Future` and an `Option`. Because you still have to return a `Future` in some form, this mainly becomes : how to handle the `Option`.

There are several possibilities :

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import cats.data.XorT
import cats.implicits._

type ServiceError = String
type FutureErrorOr[A] = XorT[Future, ServiceError, A]

val fXorT: FutureErrorOr[Int] = XorT.right(Future.successful(1))
val oXorT: XorT[Option, ServiceError, Int] = XorT.right(1.some)
```

- Turn the `Option` into a `Future` (`None` to `Future.failed`) :

  ```
  val opt2fut: FutureErrorOr[Int] = 
    XorT(oXorT.value.fold(
      Future.failed[ServiceError Xor Int](new NoSuchElementException())(
      Future.successful _))

  for { a <- fXort; b <- opt2fut } yield a + b
  ```
- Turn the `Option` into a `ServiceError Xor ?` (`None` to `Xor.Left`) :

  ```
  val opt2xor: FutureErrorOr[Int] = 
    XorT.fromXor[Future](oXorT.value.getOrElse("no elem".left))

  for { a <- fXort; b <- opt2xor } yield a + b
  ```
- Change your return type to `XorT[Future, ServiceError, Option[X]]` (this might not be useful if you need to use the `X` in the rest of the for comprehension) :

  ```
  val optInside: FutureErrorOr[Option[Int]] = 
    XorT.fromXor[Future](oXorT.value.sequenceU)

  for { a <- fXorT; b <- optInside } yield b.map(_ + a)
  ```

Comment: maybe better to make some universal container which can represent as Future or Option or any others, something like XorT[UniverseContainer, SeviceError, Value]

Comment: I am not sure how you would create such a `UniverseContainer` ?

Comment: I also think about it, as some wrapper with own flatMap - UniversalContainer(Option), UniversalContainer(Future)